# BigML connection to node JS

Tags: node.js, database, express, bigml

I want to take a Jason file (from JS)  that contains a certain data, analyze it in BigML and export it after the analysis again to the Jason file.
Then I want to use this Jason file as a table in HTML.
How do I connect bigMl to JS so that the whole process is automated (Sending the Jason file, analyzing it in BigMl and from there exporting it to HTML?)?

Comment: Since you tagged this as `express`, do you expect that the whole process is triggered by a request to a web server? Perhaps this is better executed in a batch job and the web server only serves the finished HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you divide the question into sub-problems:

1. How to take a **JSON** file (**J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, and not as you wrote **Jason**) and enter it as input to BigML.
2. How to get the output of BigML in JSON form and parse it, in order to get the prediction.
3. How to display JSON as a HTML table.

Answers:

1. To insert data into BigML you can simply drag a CSV file into the interface on their website. According to your question, I assume you don't want to do it via the interface but via programming. If I'm right, you didn't mention what programming language you're writing in. BigML has documentation and sample code on GitHub how to do it in Node.js: https://github.com/bigmlcom/bigml-node
2. In the same code example on github, the output of BigML is returned as JSON. Note that the information that is returned to you does not include the prediction results, but rather a link to a computational model that ML created based on the data you sent to it for "training". Now you can send new data to this model and receive the "prediction" results, also in JSON.
3. The undesirable way to do this, is for the server you are programming to create the HTML table, and transfer it via an API to the client. The really desirable way to do this, is for the server you are programming to transfer via API to the client only the relevant part of the JSON and the client will create the HTML table from the sub-JSON which it received from the server. Here is an example of a simple way to use JSON.stringify to turn JSON into a string and insert it into a table: https://w3schools.com/js/js_json_html.asp

If you need more help, feel free to ask. It is of course desirable in the future to break down the question into sub-problems. "Divide and rule"...